# query (with replace function) verified on mysql but not passed in spark sql

Tags: string, apache-spark-sql

my original query verified on mysql is below:

```
select substring(replace(substring(order_date, 1,10), '-',''),1, 6) as OrderMonth, c.customer_id, round(sum(oi.order_item_subtotal),2) as MonthlyTotal
from orders o join order_items oi on oi.order_item_order_id = o.order_id
join customers c on c.customer_id = o.order_customer_id
group by substring(replace(substring(order_date, 1,10), '-',''),1, 6), customer_id 
order by sum(oi.order_item_subtotal) desc 
limit 5;
```

I got error when I run it in Spark:

```
scala> val final_result = sqlContext.sql(sql_query)
18/03/14 14:03:58 INFO ParseDriver: Parsing command: select substring(replace(substring(order_date, 1,10), '-',''),1, 6) as OrderMonth, c.customer_id, round(sum(oi.order_item_subtotal),2) as MonthlyTotal
from orders o join order_items oi on oi.order_item_order_id = o.order_id
join customers c on c.customer_id = o.order_customer_id
group by substring(replace(substring(order_date, 1,10), '-',''),1, 6), customer_id
order by sum(oi.order_item_subtotal) desc
limit 5
18/03/14 14:03:58 INFO ParseDriver: Parse Completed
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: undefined function replace; line 4 pos 60
```

How do I fix the query? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

so it turns out the string function of **replace** is NOT accepted for unknown reason, I switch to use **regexp_replace**, it is working as expected now.

Can anyone share any insight? Thanks.